# WCF 101 - Object Property and KnownTypes Issue

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to web services and I am stuck at defining an object property named `MyValue` in my wcf service.

The data contract class looks sort of like this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)]
[KnownType(typeof(string))]
[KnownType(typeof(int))]
[KnownType(typeof(double))]
[KnownType(typeof(long))]
public class MyRequestMessage : DefaultRequestMessage
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int Nr { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public object MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

After deploying the service and updating the reference in my test solution I realized the reference.cs file looks completely different.

Take a look at the generated code lines:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="MyRequestMessage", Namespace="...")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<object>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<double>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<decimal>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<int>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<bool>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>>))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Type))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.SystemException))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Exception))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Reflection.MemberInfo))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.IO.FileNotFoundException))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.IO.IOException))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(...)]
public partial class MyRequestMessage : DefaultRequestMessage {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public int Nr { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public object MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

After hitting F5 in my test solution I get following error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Type cannot be added to list of known types since another type with the same data contract name is already present. If there are different collections of a particular type - for example, List<Test> and Test[], they cannot both be added as known types. Consider specifying only one of these types for addition to the known types list.
```

Why are there so many KnownTypeAttribute in there? Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you knowntypeing on the primative types?

Comment: I dont know. I am new to all this. I just want object type as property. It works all fine when I change object to string. Seems the object type screws everything up.

Comment: Remove ALL the KnownTypeAttributes on your code. Then tell me what "screws everything up" means

Comment: @Aron from Contract or from Reference.cs?

Comment: Remove from the Constract. You should not be touching Reference. Regenerate the reference.cs after.

Comment: I removed those 4 lines but error message is still the same after deploying and generating the service reference. When I change the type to String MyValue it works all fine.

Answer (score 1):

"Any ideas how to solve this issue?" ... Since you indicated that you are new to WCF, I’ll propose a rather fundamental “idea” to resolve the issue; refactor the service interface to eliminate the need for an “object” type.

Typically, when designing a WCF service interface, the parameters and return values are established and “known” by the client and service via a shared data contract.  When defining a `DataContract` with `object` parameter type, however, additional information (`KnownType` attributes) must be specified so that the serializer is able to handle the data.

In the event that you want to proceed with the “object” parameter type, the following article provides a comprehensive discussion:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms730167(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well yea but when I leave all those [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute it works fine. So what am I missing?

Comment: Oh... I thought you were having issues with an error (System.InvalidOperationException: Type cannot be added to list...).  Is the error now resolved?

Answer (score -1):

You cant have a DataMember of type object - it needs to be serializable for WCF.

Comment: You are wront it works when I leave away all the knowntypes in generated code.